# Alfresco - How to get all checked out documents?

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to get a list of all checked out documents. Unfortunately, I'm new to Alfresco and can't quite figure out how to do this. I found this:

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Get_Checked_Out_Documents_.28getCheckedOutDocs.29

Which is:

Gets the list of documents that are checked out that the user has access to.

But I don't want the checked out documents for just one user, I want the checked out documents of all users. Is there a way to get that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: What are you using to achieve this, Java backed web script?

Comment: @Lista I'm using a `.Net` framework with `C#`

Comment: And how are you communicating with Alfresco (probably CMIS)?

Comment: @Lista I'm using either the [CMIS REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html) or the [Alfresco REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/topics/pra-welcome-aara.html). Basically whichever API gets me what I am looking for

Comment: Okay, and do you have the option to add your own web script (which would also be RESTful)?

Comment: @Lista Yes I think I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is create your own web script which you would execute with admin privileges (meaning, you'd act as an administrator, you'd see the whole repository, and you'd see all the documents in it).

Now, what you're missing is a way to find all the checked out documents. Well, when you check out a document, a working copy gets created (while the original remains locked). Working copy gets the "cm:workingCopy" aspect, while the original gets the "cm:checkedOut" aspect.

All your web script needs to do is to execute an aspect based query and find what you need. You can use Node Browser to test the query before writing any code.

> ASPECT:"cm:checkedOut"

Comment: Great thanks for the help!! Is there any links to examples you could point me to of an aspect based query? Furthermore what exactly is node browser? Sorry just learning so :)

Comment: Node Browser is a part of Share, basically a place where you can browse through the nodes, see their properties, aspects, and run queries. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/adminconsole-nodebrowser.html, https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mUdPL_rYkiw/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually just found that too :)

Comment: What does the `cm` signify?

Comment: Content model namespace, see https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Built-in_Content_Model_Namespaces

Comment: Thanks for the link!! :)