# How to search for an aspect/property?

Tags: c#, alfresco

So I'm looking to get a list of all checked out documents based on [aspects](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Aspect), specifically `cm:checkedOut` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927969/alfresco-how-to-get-all-checked-out-documents).

Basically, I want to search for all documents with the aspect `cm:checkedOut` and assume that that would be the list of all checked out documents.

I've been able to use this in the [node browser](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/adminconsole-nodebrowser.html), but I'm having a hard time finding a REST endpoint that will let me search for a certain aspect.The only thing I found useful was [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Query) CMIS endpoint:

> Executes a CMIS query statement against the contents of the Repository.
>
> `GET /alfresco/service/cmis/query?q={q}&includeAllowableActions={includeAllowableActions?}&includeRelationships={includeRelationships?}&renditionFilter={renditionFilter?}&searchAllVersions={searchAllVersions?}&skipCount={skipCount?}&maxItems={maxItems?}`

And I'm assuming I'd have to write a query something like [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#CMIS_Query). But I'm new to Alfresco and I honestly don't know if I can write a CMIS query to search for a particular aspect?

So my question is: is there a REST endpoint that will let me search for a specific aspect and do what I want to find? If it's relevant, I'm using a `.NET` framework with `C#`.

Comment: Hi ocean800, my old friend :) Is there a reason you're insisting on CMIS, are you happy with anything RESTful that gets the job done?

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you using? Only more recent versions have a wider range of REST endpoints available

Comment: @Lista Hello again! :) I'm happy with anything RESTful really that gets the job done. This is simply what I found that might be useful

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using Alfresco 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Download the [Apache CMIS workbench](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/chemistry/opencmis/0.14.0/chemistry-opencmis-workbench-0.14.0-full.zip), configure the workbench to use the **CMIS 1.0** specification cause the dotCMIS implementation only supports 1.0

And your query is very simple, just use: **SELECT * FROM cm:checkedOut**

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will look more into this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can always browse all web scripts and see if there's anything for you there that can do the job.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/uri/

Depending on your version of Alfresco, you can use the new Swagger based API explorer, example here.

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/

If you look at what Share uses (it means that it's OOTB available) for it's advanced search, you get this.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/uri/slingshot/node/search

It has a bunch of parameters you need to send (test this by searching through Share and using Firebug) but the main one is the "query" one, which is basically a JSON of properties you search with.

> {"prop_cm_name":"45445656","prop_cm_title":"","prop_cm_description":"","prop_mimetype":"","prop_cm_modified-date-range"
>   :"","prop_cm_modifier":"","datatype":"cm:content"}